# When copying from one workbook to another, an "unwanted" workbook is created

Tags: vba, excel

So I have two excel workbooks - Workbook A is used as a userform and Workbook B as a database with all the data entries (B is a merged file). Whenever I open Workbook A, I would like to pull all the data from Workbook B automatically and copy it into Workbook A in a separate Worksheet. In doing so, I can implement some other functionalities like retrieval of previous entries.

So I used the following cod embedded in Workbook:

```
Public Sub Workbook_open()

Call get_AllUpdateEntries

End Sub


Sub get_AllUpdateEntries()

Dim oriWorkbook As Workbook
Dim destWorkbook As Workbook

Set oriWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("FilePath")
Set destWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

oriWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet Name").Copy

destWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet Name").Paste

x.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

However, I cannot get this macro running. It doesn't copy the Worksheet as I want, and additionally, another, unwanted Workbook is opened.

Comment: Where you have `Workbooks.Open("FilePath")` the FilePath should be an actual path, such as _C:\Desktop\MyWorkbook.xlsx_

Comment: When you copy a worksheet to no destination you create another new active workbook with a single worksheet (copy of the original). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088589/error-in-copying-a-sheet-from-one-workbook-to-an-another/52088633#52088633

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you copy the worksheet to no location, it creates a new active workbook with a single worksheet (a copy of the original).

Provide an immediate destination for the copied worksheet.

```
Sub get_AllUpdateEntries()

    Dim oriWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim destWorkbook As Workbook

    Set oriWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("FilePath")
    Set destWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

    'remove the destination worksheet if it already exists
    on error resume next
    application.displayalerts = false
    destWorkbook.worksheets("All Update Entries").delete
    application.displayalerts = true
    on error goto 0

    'copy worksheet to the end of the worksheet queue in ThisWorkbook
    oriWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet Name").Copy _
       After:=destWorkbook.Sheets(destWorkbook.Sheets.count)

    oriWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'rename the transferred worksheet
    destWorkbook.Sheets(destWorkbook.Sheets.count).name = "All Update Entries"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Jeeped! Now I can copy Worksheet from oriWorkbook to destWorkbook. But this always creates a new Worksheet in destWorkbook. What do I have to do if I want to paste it in a particular Worksheet called All Update Entries? Do I have to replace destWorkbook.Sheets.count with "All Update Entries"?

Comment: Don't copy the sheet, copy the cells: `oriWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet Name").Usedrange.Copy destWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet Name").Range("A1")`

Comment: @NKAR, I've adjusted the method to remove any original and rename the new copied worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs! I just have a one last question. Will Worksheet All Update Entries be overwritten when I reopen the file?

Comment: Actually, it will be deleted and a new *All Update Entries* will be created from the oriWorkbook.